# Слушатель событий для scrollview

Tags: android, события, прокрутка, listener

Eclipse под Android. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли у scrollview слушатель событий который реагирует на перемещение того что в окне(в моём случае текста)?
Допустим примерно так `scrollview.addMottionListener` (код или функция которую надо выполнять во время прокрутки,например получать вертикальную координату и в определённый момент не особо заметно для пользователя выполнить подгрузку текста и выгрузить из памяти невидимый).

Задача состоит в том что бы динамически подгружать и выгружать текст из оперативной памяти (ибо страшно тормозят 800 kB текста).

И ещё, раньше программировал на as3 под флэш, там была такая тема как слушатель событий экрана в паре с таймером, `stage.addEventListener(......)`,в эклипсе есть что нибудь подобное?

Comment: А платформу и язык мы должны угадать, чтобы интереснее было?

Comment: Eclipse android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я делаю так:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
            }
        });
```